# SQL getting empty fields from other table

Tags: mysql, sql

i am working with views for the first time.
I can see the records from table `Student` in the view, but the records from table `Course` are not shown getting NULL everywhere.

Here are the tables I created:

```
-- Tabel StudentCourse maken
CREATE TABLE StudentCourse
(
StudentCourse int NOT NULL,
CourseId int NOT NULL,
StudentId int NOT NULL
)
-- DROP table StudentCourse

-- Tabel Course maken
CREATE TABLE Course
(
CourseId int NOT NULL,
Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
StartDate date NOT NULL,
EndDate date NOT NULL,
Period int NOT NULL,
IsWeekEnd bit NOT NULL,
IsActive bit NOT NULL
)
-- DROP table Course

-- Tabel Student maken
CREATE TABLE Student
(
StudentId int NOT NULL,
Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Age int NOT NULL,
Address varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Registered datetime NOT NULL,
IsActive bit NOT NULL,
Description varchar(255) NOT NULL
)
-- DROP table Student
```

And here is the view i created

```
CREATE VIEW V AS (

  SELECT s.StudentId,s.Name,c.CourseId,c.StartDate FROM
    Student s
  LEFT JOIN 
    Course c 
  ON
    s.Name=c.Name
);
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Why would you expect any students to have the same name as their course?  Your data model is missing a `StudentCourses` table.

Comment: Note that the surrogate PK column StudentCourse is redundant. You have a perfectly serviceable PK on the remaining columns.

Comment: Incidentally, and FWIW, I think views in MySQL are *almost* pointless.

Answer (score 0):

There are no Courses with the same name as names from students. You need to LEFT JOIN Student on StudentCourse and INNER JOIN StudentCourse on Course.

```
SELECT s.StudentId,s.Name,c.CourseId,c.StartDate 
FROM Student s
LEFT JOIN StudentCourse sc ON s.StudentId = sc.StudentId
INNER JOIN Course c ON sc.CourseId = c.CourseId
```

Comment: If you LEFT JOIN one then surely you need to LEFT JOIN the other !?!